# Referencing outside of directory

Tags: html, css

I have a website with a multiple pages some of which are in a seperate directory. However, I can't seem to link pages in one directory to a css file in a separate directory.

I have tried the pasting entire directory and css/main.css.

//Here is the folder/directory structure of my project

> home.html
>   css
>   --main.css
>   lines
>   --M51.html
>   --M50.html
>   --M53.html

Here is the HTML code I use to reference to the css in html file M51.html or any file in lines folder/directory:

> < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" media="screen" />

When testing the html page in lines folder(M51 or M52 or M53), I see css is not applied and error "cannot resolve file css/main.css". How can I resolve this error?

It works fine on home.html but not on those inside the "lines" directory.

Comment: What exactly is a 'map'?

Comment: I just searched and it is apperently called file directory in English. srry, native language is Dutch.

Comment: Please be a little more specific: What programming language are you working with? Can you paste the code where you include the css?

Comment: Reference the file using ../css/main.css for files in the lines directory(map).
css directory(map) is located in the folder one level up from the current folder.
Relative Path for external CSS

Comment: tarun khosla, thanks. You saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have Css files stored in a different directory. Make sure you use relative file path to include css in the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" media="screen" />
```

A relative file path points to a file relative to the current page.

> **Best Practice**
>
> It is best practice to use relative file paths (if
>   possible).
>
> When using relative file paths, your web pages will not be bound to
>   your current base URL. All links will work on your own computer
>   (localhost) as well as on your current public domain and your future
>   public domains.

Answer (score 0):

Copying an answer from the comments because it is the right answer:

Reference the file using this:

../css/main.css

for files in the "lines" directory (map). The two dots go up one level, where the "css" directory(map) is located relative to the current folder. Use the Relative Path for the external CSS file.